# Bash script to replace content of line with information in a consequent line (sed)

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I have a File.txt listing several items and additional details in consequent lines included in square brackets []:

```
item name1,
item name2,
item name3,
item name4,
some text
on several lines
detail name1;
detail name2[moreinfo];
detail name3[can contain numbers and characters:1];
detail name4;
```

and I would like to modify it such that the details of each items are appended in the previous lines to have the following expected output:

```
item name1,
item name2[moreinfo],
item name3[can contain numbers and characters:1],
item name4,
some text
on several lines
detail name1;
detail name2[moreinfo];
detail name3[can contain numbers and characters:1];
detail name4;
```

Is there any easy sed expression to do this when the number of items is not known?
I would like something like:

```
sed -i '/detail \(.*\)\[\(.*\)\]/ s/item \1/item \1\[\2\]/g' File.txt
```

but I know that back-reference is not working like this.

Comment: Um ... the title says "_Bash script_," in the question you specifically ask for "_easy sed expression_" -- while the tags contain "_perl_".  Which is it? Any of them?  If so, remove explicit mentions of particular languages (and do show what you tried in `sed`)

Comment: It seems like something hard to do with `sed`

Comment: could a `nameX` field have different contents inside square brackets? for example, can the following occur: `item name5[some_info]` + `details name5[more_info]` and if this can occur, then what's the expected output? (also, if this can occur then please update the sample data and expected output to demonstrate the issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^item (.*),(?=(?:.|\n)*^detail \1(\[.*\]))/item $1$2,/mg'
```

It uses the `-0777` (could be shortened to `-g` since Perl 5.36) to read the whole file in as a single string. The substitution uses the `(?=...)` look-ahead assertion to search for the corresponding detail.

Comment: `perl -g` with Perl >= 5.36 instead of `-0777`

Comment: @GillesQuénot: Thaks for the comment, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tac` and any `awk`:

```
$ tac file |
    awk -F'[[ ,;]' '
        ($1 == "detail") && match($0,/\[.*]/) { det[$2] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }
        ($1 == "item") && ($2 in det) { sub(/,$/,""); $0 = $0 det[$2] "," }
        { print }
    ' |
    tac
item name1,
item name2[moreinfo],
item name3[can contain numbers and characters:1],
item name4,
some text
on several lines
detail name1;
detail name2[moreinfo];
detail name3[can contain numbers and characters:1];
detail name4;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
        if ($0 ~ /^detail /){
            sub(/^detail /,"item ")
            sub(/;$/,",")
            key=value=$0
            sub(/\[.*\]/,"",key)
            a[key] = value
        }
        next
    }   
    {
        if ($0 in a) 
            print a[$0]
        else
            print
    }
' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;$!d;x
        :a;s/(\nitem ([^,]+))(,.*\ndetail \2(\[[^[]+\]);)/\1\4\3/;ta;s/.//' file
```

Slurp the file into hold space and then iterate a substitution using pattern matching on the same name for the item and detail, inserting a bracketed string following the detail after a matching item name. When there are no further matches remove the leading introduced newline and print the result.

Alternative slightly shorter solution:

```
sed -zE ':a;s/(item ([^,]+))(,.*detail \2(\[[^[]+\]);)/\1\4\3/;ta' file
```